# PHP Framework + LDAP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, frameworks, ldap

For my professional project I need to work with LDAP and MySQL. I don’t have any constraint with the Framework I just need to use PHP (5.3 exactly).

So I just have a question:

With your experience, which PHP Framework is really good to connect easily my system with the LDAP? I have other technical constraints with this project so I don’t want to pass 1 week to code my auth system

I “love” Symfony2 (last version) but I need to code my LDAP auth system (I checked for Symfony2.4 I need to do more or less everything?!).

It’s really easy to code with Symfony2 with the form helper system, validators, CRUD generator, Doctrine, etc, but it’s not my priority.

Maybe Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO selecting a framework does not depend on just one feature or one attribute (in your case using LDAP). There are different libraries which you can use to do ldap authentication in simple php than using a complete framework.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php